# In Rails, how to call an AJAX function and then refresh page when its complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form where I if a user changes the value in one of the drop-down-lists then it needs to change some controls on the form.  The way it's currently set up...

1. On drop-down-list change, executes an AJAX call to save the form with new value
2. Before the "update" method executes on my object I mark deleted fields that do not pertain to the new value that was changed
3. In the `success` function of the AJAX call it executes a `location.reload()`

The current problem is that the reload occurs sometimes before the auto-save method has completed.  How can I only reload the page until after the auto-save has fully completed?  I don't want to set `async: false` in the `$.ajax` because it freezes the entire page before my message to the user is shown telling them to please wait.  Please let me know if I've forgotten any code to include below thanks!

**reports.coffee**

```
  autoSavePost = (reload) ->
  console.log('autosave executed');
  $.ajax
    type: 'PUT'
    url: '/reports/autosave'
    data: $('#report-form').serialize()
    dataType: 'script'
    success: (data) ->
      if reload
        setTimeout(location.reload(), 5000);
      return true
    error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) ->
      console.log xhr.responseText.substr(0,1500)
      return false
  # schedule the next autosave
  if $('#auto-save').length
    setTimeout autoSavePost, 60000
  else
    return false

  return

$ ->
      $(document).on 'change', '#report_position_id', (evt) ->
        $.blockUI({ message: '<h5>Please wait, "Position Graded" is being changed...</h5>' });
        # grey out screen with message until page reloads.
        autoSavePost(true)
        return
```

Comment: Not sure why "location.reload()" is firing before success completes, but you should be scheduling the next autosave in that success callback so the requests don't stack up.

Comment: @mnort9, thanks! good call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

render js from the controller function, and the js file that gets rendered call window.reload.

or render head :ok which will trigger ajax success, and then window.reload